# How can I calculate average from values with different measurement errors?

Tags: average

`l1`, `l2`, and `l3` have the following values:

`l1 = 14.0 ± 0.05`, `l2 = 32.0 ± 0.05`, `l3 = 49.0 ± 0.05`

These values are respectively `1/4`, `3/4`, and `5/4` of the wavelength of a stationary wave. So I have to calculate out the wavelength with some subtraction and multiplication. Hope you understand what I'm trying to do..

So these are the values I calculated:

`2(L3-L2) = 34.0 ± 0.2`, `2(L2-L1) = 36.0 ± 0.2`, `L3-L1 = 35.0 ± 0.1`

I want to get the average of these values; but I have no idea how to do this when some of the values have different measurement errors.

Comment: It is not possible to have $l_1$, $l_2$ and $l_3$ as the fractions you have mentioned of the wavelength. Since $l_3$ is the largest and $l_1$ should be the smallest, $l_3$ should be $5(l_1)$,, but it is only $3.5$ times.

Comment: What are you trying to do? Can you explain why have you tried to get the average of the values? Without some context it's really hard to understand the question, and hoping that someone will understand is generally a really bad idea (no one will if you don't explain enough).